# Observer not clearing cache in Rails 2.3.2 - please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

We are using Rails 2.3.2, Ruby 1.8 & memcache.

In my Posts controller I have:

```
cache_sweeper Company::Caching::Sweepers::PostSweeper, :only => [:save_post]
```

I have created the following module:

```
module Company
  module Caching
    module Sweepers

      class PostSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
        observe Post

        def after_save(post)
          Rails.cache.delete("post_" + post.permalink)
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

but when the save_post method is invoked, the cache is never deleted. Just hoping someone can see what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the action in the controller is called `save_post`, your sweeper method should be called `after_save_post(post)`.

Answer (score 0):

probably you didn't add the sweeper in your load path

```
 config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/cache )
```

where the directory is where your sweepers are located.